# What does #Type! mean in a textbox which is referencing a subform field, Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a datasheet subform that has `unit_price`, `Quantity` and `Line_Price`.

`Line_Price = [unit_price]*[Quantity]`

I have then added a textbox in the footer, which is purposefully not visable in the datasheet view. this textbox is called `subtotal`.

`subtotal = sum([Line_Price])`

Now when I add a textbox in the mainform with the following control:

`="total: " & [subform].[form]![subtotal]`

I get the following return as a value in form view : "#Type!"

I got the idea for this approach from this [website](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/subform-total.html). However, I am clearly not getting the correct result for some reason. Does anyone know what it means by #Type! or how to correct my *"mistake*"? Thanks.

Comment: This usually occurs when your try to mix a string and a number value.  Simplest solution is make the "total: " your text box caption and just use the textbox to display the subtotal value. (you can change the background and border of either the textbox or caption to get the effect you're after). If you're dead set on doing it all in text box, you'll have to convert the number to a string first.

Comment: I've removed the "total: " and now the return value is '#Error'. It clearly was one part of my problem, but there must be something else I am doing wrong also.

Comment: Check your reference. I'm guessing that your visible text box is in the main form and your hidden text box is in a subform.  Google search "access referencing a subform" and you'll get a couple million hits on how to do this properly.  Should be something along the lines of "= forms!mainformName.SubformName.forms!ControlonSubform"

Comment: I've figured out what is wrong, or at least got my form functioning... It turns out you cannot sum calculated fields in forms, according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/207763). So I used `subtotal=sum([Quantity]*[Unit_Price])`

Comment: That should have shown up in the value on your hidden textbox. I guess I incorrectly assumed that the subtotal field was working correctly.